# Does Spring Data JPA have a naming convention for "member of"?

Tags: java, jpql, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA constructs a number of queries based on naming convention of the interface methods. Is there any naming convention to do a ["MEMBER OF" query](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection#NOT_MEMBER_OF_)?

I can get the following to work with JPQL:

```
@Query("select e from MyEntity e where ?1 member of e.entities")
```

However, I'd like to use a name convention method if possible. I couldn't find anything in the docs about it, so I'm hoping I'm just missing something. If there's some fundamental reason there can't be methods for this, I'd be interested to know that too.

Comment: I guess they forgot about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skimming the latest version of this document it doesn't look like there is. Here are the available method name keywords:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#d0e1599

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to be incomplete about the `Containing` (`IsContaining`, `Contains`) key word.

https://dzone.com/refcardz/core-spring-data extends the documentation as follows:

> CONTAINING:   Containing, IsContaining, Contains (String **or collection
> types** only)

So you are able to use the `Containing` key word as a replacement for `member of`.

For example:

```
// select e from MyEntity e where ?1 member of e.entities
findByEntitiesContaining(TypeOfMember member);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer provided by Zerlono didn't work for me.

However, I achieved the desired effect through the use of findDistinctBy and by emitting `Containing`. Seems illogical, I know, but got the job done:

```
// select e from MyEntity e where ?1 member of e.entities
findDistinctByEntities(TypeOfMember member);
```